# EntityManagerFactory interface [interface org.hibernate.SessionFactory] seems to conflict with Spring's EntityManagerFactoryInfo mixin

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jakarta-migration

Hello I have this problem with my spring boot application:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dbEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource ...: EntityManagerFactory interface [interface org.hibernate.SessionFactory] seems to conflict with Spring's EntityManagerFactoryInfo mixin - consider resetting the 'entityManagerFactoryInterface' property to plain [jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1231)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:949)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1454)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)
    ... 17 more
```

My pom.xml connected dependencies are:

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> 
  <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </parent>
```

And this is my DatabaseConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "dbEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "dbTransactionManager", basePackages = {
    "..."})
@EntityScan("...")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    private final YamlProperties yamlProperties;

    @Bean(name = "dbDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dbDataSourceProperties() {

        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dbDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("dbDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties dbDataSourceProperties) {

        return dbDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();

    }

    @Bean(name = "dbEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        @Qualifier("dbDataSource") DataSource dbDataSource) {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dbDataSource);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", getDatabaseUrl());
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", "CCN2_SCHEMA");
        em.setJpaProperties(properties);
        em.setPackagesToScan("eu.europa.ec.taxud.ssv.earchiving_archiving_agent_kibana_pdf_recovery.repository.model");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("dbDataSource");

        return em;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dbTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager dbTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("dbEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory dbEntityManagerFactory) {

        return new JpaTransactionManager(dbEntityManagerFactory);
    }

    public String getDatabaseUrl() {

        return String.format(
            "%s;USER=%s;PASSWORD=%s;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=true;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS CCN2_SCHEMA;",
            yamlProperties.getAppProperties().getDatabaseProperties().getSpringDatasourceUrl(),
            yamlProperties.getAppProperties().getDatabaseProperties().getSpringDatasourceUsername(),
            yamlProperties.getAppProperties().getDatabaseProperties().getSpringDatasourcePassword());
    }

}
```

Is it the problem with versions of spring boot and jakarta dependencies? Right now they are both the newest I tried some conifugrations but it didn't work. Before i had older version of springboot and javax instead of jakarta and it was working pretty well, but now I need them to be relatively the newest